# Programmatically switch view controller to show views in Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to figure out how I can programmatically switch the views from one view controller to a first view controller in a Tab bar controller when I press a button.

Currently I have a view controller with three buttons. When I press a button I would like to then switch. This is the following code I have for this screen. It is called the second view controller.

```
    import UIKit

    class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    //Button Outlets
    @IBOutlet var ButtonEndOfShift: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var ButtonMultiTimes: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var ButtonEndAndLunch: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //hides tab bar controller
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Changes screen for End Of Shift Button
    @IBAction func ChangeNextViewLow(sender: AnyObject) {


        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
    }

    //Changes screen for Lunch and End Of Shift Button
    @IBAction func ChangeNextViewMedium(sender: UIButton) {
    }

    //Changes screen for Multiple Times button
    @IBAction func ChangeNextViewHigh(sender: UIButton) {
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: set tabbarcontroller to root view controller on tap of button

Comment: Why are you performing segue? Don't you want to switch from one tab to another tab of the tab bar controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added `UITabBarController` in `Storyboard` like below please see images.

[image]
[image]

Then i have written following `functions` for your help.

```
// For navigate to Tabbar Controller
    @IBAction func btnClick () {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToTabBar", sender: nil)
    }

    // For switching between tabs
    func switchTab (index : Int) {
       self.tabbarController.selectedIndex = index
    }
```

You can also set `UITabBarController` as your application `RootViewController`.

Comment: self.performSegueWithIdentifier worked. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome :-) @AlexPriest

Answer (score 1):

Implement Code For didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
firstViewController *firstTab = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCntrl1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];

secViewController *secTab = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCntrl2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secTab];

thirdViewController *thirdTab = [[thirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"thirdViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCntrl3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdTab];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navCntrl1, navCntrl2, navCntrl3];

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```